Calling service from a service in multi-tier application structure - this is a bad idea, what is an alternative?
This is one example for MVC structure:
View layer -> Controller layer -> Service layer -> Repository layer
View layer -> Controller layer -> Repository layer

In general approach if you need to do some simple data query your Controller layer can call Repository layer directly.
And this is all fine at the beginning. When code and logic start to grow there will be an issue that some services need to share the same logic. If we put the this logic in one service other services need to call this service and we get this scenario:
View layer -> Controller layer -> Service layer -> service layer

And for me this is a bad practice because this can lead to circular references e.g. service1 -> service2 -> service1, especially if you are using dependency injection container.
One solution for this will be to introduce one extra sub layer and put common logic there, e.g.
View layer -> Controller layer -> Service layer -> Sub layer

The problem with this is what naming conventions to use and how to name the classes in this sub layers when code starts to grow and number of those sub layers starts also to grow? Or maybe there are some other techniques for dealing with this problem?

(With the caution that I would not call what you describe initially MVC, but that is another story.)

how to name the classes in this sub layers when code starts to grow and number of those sub layers starts also to grow?

There are no common conventions AFAIK, I call these "managers": e.g. Identity Manager, Data Manager, Communications Manager, etc., where these "managers" are simply libraries, and ideally their methods are units of work.
Since managers must be able to depend on each other, a next level would be to have these dependencies not on concrete implementations, only on shared interfaces: in other words, concrete managers would implement functionality that is defined in abstract shared interfaces.  But IMO this is only warranted for systems where concrete components do vary, so e.g. with dependency injection.
